# Validar si un nombre de imagen existe en una ruta

Tags: c#

estoy intentado validar si un nombre de imagen obtenido desde mi base de datos existe en un directorio.
ejempo:

```
if(imagen001 ==ruta\xx\imagen001)
{
mensaje: Si tiene imagen
}
```

En este caso voy a tener muchos nombres de imagen en la base de datos, así como también en mi carpeta de imágenes.

Comment: y cual es la pregunta?

Comment: Gracias. ya logre realizarlo. if (!File.Exists(ruta_imagen))
                    {
                        string f_guia = guias.Listar_Guias_xMes_xAño(Convert.ToInt32(mes),
                        Convert.ToInt32(año)).Rows[o][1].ToString();
                        objguias.InsertarGuiasValidadas(nom_imagen_db,
                        Convert.ToDateTime(f_guia), Convert.ToDateTime(fecha_actual), 0);
                        //MessageBox.Show("Insertando Registro" + nom_imagen_db);
                    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tienes la ruta y el nombre del archivo independientemente puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
string ruta = @"D:\cursos\ASP.NET";
string archivo = "mi_curso.pdf";
if(File.Exists(ruta+"\\"+archivo)){
  Console.WriteLine("Existe el archivo: "+archivo);
} else {
  Console.WriteLine("No existe");
}
```

Recuerda incluir al comienzo de tu archivo:

```
using System.IO;
```

Si lo que quieres saber es si en una ruta dada como cadena contiene el nombre de un archivo específico puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
string ruta = @"D:\cursos\ASP.NET\mi_curso.pdf";
string archivo = "mi_curso.pdf";
if(Path.FileName(ruta) == archivo){
  Console.WriteLine("Existe el archivo: "+archivo);
} else {
  Console.WriteLine("No existe");
}
```

Se podria realizar este ultimo con la función IndexOf que tienen las cadenas pero deberias comprobar que la posición encontrada sea la ultima posible es decir:

```
string ruta = @"D:\cursos\ASP.NET\mi_curso.pdfs";
string archivo = "mi_curso.pdf";
if (ruta.ToLower().IndexOf(archivo.ToLower()) == ruta.Length - archivo.Length)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Existe el archivo: " + archivo);
}
else
{
   Console.WriteLine("No existe");
 }
```

Si quieres buscar exactamente que se llame igual el archivo, con distinción de mayúsculas y minúsculas; puedes quitar el .ToLower() donde quiera que aparezca en el ultimo ejemplo es decir quedaria de esta manera:

```
if (ruta.IndexOf(archivo) == ruta.Length - archivo.Length)
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrias cargar las imagene en una lista en memoria usando

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\\ruta\xx\imagen001", "*.jpg");

List<string> fileNames = files.Select(x=> Path.GetFileName(x)).ToList();
```

la idea del `Select()` es obtenr los nombres de los arhivos ya que el `GetFiles()` no da la ruta completa

entonces despues iteras los datos de la db

```
//codigo de acceso a la db
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while(reader.Read()){

   string fileName = reader["fileName"].ToString();

   if(fileNames.Contains(fileName)){
      //existe en la carpeta
   }

}
```